# Refactoring using LINQ, C# and Lists NetworkInterface

Tags: c#, linq, list, foreach

I want use only LINQ statement for the following method. I return List of strings, but first I get List of NetworkInterface.

```
public static List<string> ObtenerDireccionesDeInterfacesDeRedActivos()
{
    var listaDirecciones = new List<string>();
    var interfacesActivos =
        (from networkInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            let
                /*IPv4InterfaceStatistics*/
                statistics = networkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics()
            where
                // filter so we see only Internet adapters                
                networkInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
                && networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel
                && networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback

                // all testing seems to prove that once an interface comes online      
                // it has already accrued statistics for both received and sent...  
                && (statistics.BytesReceived > 0) && (statistics.BytesSent > 0)
            select
            networkInterface).ToList<NetworkInterface>();

    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in interfacesActivos)
    {
        var ips = nic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses;
        foreach (var ip in ips)
        {
            listaDirecciones.Add(ip.Address.ToString());
        }
    }

    return listaDirecciones;
}
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ToList<NetworkInterface>()` call is unnecessary.  There is no reason why you should have to turn this query into a list before enumerating it.

Additionally, you might consider having this method return an `IEnumerable<string>` (instead of `listaDirecciones.Add(ip.Address.ToString());` just do `yield return ip.Address.ToString()`) and let the caller decide if they need to convert it into a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your loop with the following code:

```
return new List<string>(
    from nic in interfacesActivos
    from ips in nic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
    select ip.Address.ToString());
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer @cdhowie's answer to mine, but if you want to return a `List<string>`, my solution should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your last `loop` with:

```
return interfacesActivos.SelectMany(nic => nic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                        .Select(ip => ip.ToString())
                        .ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

As **[cdhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855194/refactoring-using-linq-c-and-lists-networkinterface/4855231#4855231)** said, you can skip the `ToList<NetworkInterface>()`.

Also, depending on your needs, you can skip the `ToList()` of my code snippet too, and just returning a `IEnumerable<string>`